# Civilization V versions

Tags: civilization-5

I want to purchase a Hard copy of Civilization V. I would like this to contain the Manual and the flowchart that shows technological advances. When you try and look into this those items are rarely mentioned. They are not even mentioned in the Contents for the Collectors Edition. I know they exist because I have seen them on a demo on youtube. Also I believe the basic version is missing some Features/Civilizations. Does anyone know which version I need to buy to get a full version and to get all the literature that I mentioned please?

Comment: The Digital Deluxe edition is the only one to contain the Babylonians (as best as I know).

Comment: Thank you for that. Kind of ironic that is, since it was there that gave birth to "civilization". Any idea on the editions containing the literature I require?

Answer (score 6):

Multiple editions of Civlization 5 have been released.

Some as retail **boxed** versions, others as digital downloads.

The premium editions contain bonuses which range from:

- metalic figurines
- art work
- music tracks
- behind the scenes videos
- extra civilizations
- map packs
- posters / misc. memorabilia

Many retail stores provided different or **unique** perks included in the list above, so it is difficult to give a full list. Also it is not possible to buy a **supreme** version with all the perks listed above.

Note that **There is no hard copy manual released with any versions of Civlization 5**, <s>further more there are no hard copies of the technology tree</s>.

See this link: http://www.civilization5.com/#/community/feature_socialresponsibility

> We’ve made the formerly 200+ page printed manual an improved interactive PDF. This PDF manual allows you to click on screenshots to see them clearer than thumbnails, navigate much easier with clickable links, and most importantly, look forward to manual updates as we make changes to the game. But don’t take my word for it; I have a sample of the manual for you to check out: Click here to see the sample. **Included in the retail copies is a small quick-start manual to get you up and running as quickly as possible.**

The last sentence references a small pamphlet included in retail copies, but not the full manual.

What you may have seen on youtube was the **Collectors edition artwork book**
[image: Collectors edition artwork book]

This is **not the manual**, but a picture book containing artwork related to the game.
As far as I know, this edition was only produced as a **once only** batch when the game was released and it is quite difficult to find copies for sale.

Comment: There *is* a hard copy of the tech tree included in physical copies of the game, I know this because **I've got one** - it came on a large folded-up poster in my physical-copy (the "basic" version).

Comment: Yes there is DMA and it wasn't the collectors edition that I saw. The edition I saw had no miniatures. It had both CDs, game and soundtrack. It had the Tech Tree and both the Artwork book and the manual. Both softback.

Comment: @Sheldon: Do you have a link so we can see it too? I have never seen any copy such as the one you describe and I reviewed all the available copies for sale when the game came out.

Answer (score 3):

There's no *features* different between the versions, but some had extra scenarios/maps/civs to play. Some of these extras can be bought as DLC for other versions, if desired - the [Babylonian civilisation](http://store.steampowered.com/app/16868/) and some of the [bonus maps](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/6820/) are available by this method.

I believe no version of the game comes with a hard-copy manual - it's all [PDF](http://www.2kgames.com/manual/civ5/) - but any physical-copy version of the game does comes with a large poster that has the tech-tree flow chart as well as information on the civics and units (and other bits? I haven't got mine to hand to check).

Answer (score 2):

I got this one: http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B003ELORWE

It came with the poster, but the manual is just a PDF on the disk.

Comment: Thank you for that Info. Didn't know that version had the poster. But I also know that that version is missing the Babylonian Civilisation, so as well as the manual it isn't the Edition I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a way to get the DLC content, steam is currently selling *all* of the pre-order bonus map packs as a single bundle.

Here's the link: http://store.steampowered.com/sub/6820

For what it's worth, the Babylonian civ is also available through steam (for 5$).